# Raid only half a Disk on 2 Disk Synology NAS

Tags: raid, nas, synology

I currently have a Synology DS215j 2Bay Nas populated with 2x4TB Drives using Synology's SHR (similar to RAID1), and therefore 4TB of redundant storage.

There are 2 categories of Data on the Nas: "Unimportant" TV Shows and Movies and important files.

Is it possible to split my Raid Array in a way that I get 3 Volumes total:

-2TB redundant storage (2x2TB in RAID 1)

-2x2TB normal storage (one for each physical disk)

That way I would 'gain' an additional 2TB (for a total of 6TB) at the cost of loosing redundancy which I do not necessarily need. I have already backed up all data on the NAS.

Comment: You are not going to be able to partition your disk and assigned partitions of different disks to different RAID arrays.  What you want requires 4 seperate physical disks.

Comment: Can't I create 2 logical partitions on each disk and then do a software raid on these partitions or something similar?

Comment: No.  Even if it accepts it, it is a horrible idea, if one of the drives fails you lose the data on other partition ont he drive.  You are better off just increasing the size of the two disks in the RAID, if you want more storage, or increasing the number of disks in the RAID itself.  I hope you understand using a RAID is **NOT** a valid backup solution.  *You still have to backup the RAID itself.*

Comment: Yeah I know that I would loose the data on the other partition, but it is not important data. I currently do not have the funds to buy bigger drives, so I was hoping to cheap out. But unfortunately, I have not found such an option on my Synology yet. Maybe there is a hidden option somewhere?

Comment: Your not going to be able to setup 2 separate RAIDs on 2 disks even if its just JSOB and RAID 1

Comment: One drive for fun. One drive for serious. That's pretty much the only way you can make your current setup work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I do not think it is a horrible idea at all. I'm thinking about the same thing, because there is a huge amount of unimportant data (for those I do not want to waste a space) and some data which I would like to have fault tolerant, but not backuped. Typically, TV-shows, Time-machine backups on JSOB and photos in RAID1 (I do not need incremental backups for photos). 
Unfortunately, I do not found a way to do that and moreover I'm afraid it could influence also the overall performance. But, I made a work around.
I created folders with important data on Volume1 and set-up a backuping of these folders to Volume2. In that way, I have Volume2 for time-machine backups (I do not need to make a "backup" of backups) and for backups from Volume1. At Volume1 I have the "original" important data and unimportant data. However, I lost the RAID1 performance improvement. This solution is not perfect neither super-elegant, but it works and I've not found a better one so far.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the author's question.  You should edit this answer and provide specific and detailed steps on how the author solves their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and I tried very hard but it wasn't possible. In a DS218+ I had 1 x 4TB and 1 x 8TB and I wanted to mirror 4TB and use the spare (or "unused" as Synology calls it) as a separate volume. Your case as I understand it you want 2 of those.

I began with the 8TB disk installed and I wanted to create 2 pools. The Synology GUI only allows a disk to be part of one storage pool so I thought I would try the command line, I used `mdadm` and I found 3 RAID 1s on the disk. The first 2 are for the OS then there was the main 7TB or so main one. Synology calls "Basic" a single RAID 1. I used `mdadm` to stop this RAID. Then I used fdisk to delete this partition and create 2 in its place, roughly 4TB each. Then I used `mdadm` to create RAID 1s on both of these partitions. All went smooth until I ran the GUI to look for my 2 storage pools and sadly there were none. Then when I ran create pool it deleted my 2 partitions and created 1 big one again and added the large RAID too.

I'm just going to use both disks as "Basic" and use backup the important files on the large disk to the small instead of mirroring.

FYI I was able to use `mdadm` to remove the large RAID 1 and create a smaller one with --size and it did show up in the storage pool but that probably isn't useful to anyone but it was an interesting test.

Here is what it looked like at the last step:

```
ash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md3 : active raid1 sda4[0]
      6735695168 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0]
      1073740800 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0]
      2097088 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      2490176 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```